# Resource Not found error when trying to create a Subscription Plan for Paypal in Go

Tags: go, paypal

I am using Paypal SDK for Go to create a plan and I am getting the error:

```
Request: GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans?page=1&page_size=5&status=ACTIVE&total_required=no. Data: 
Response: HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Date: Mon, 01 Mar 2021 14:51:21 GMT
Paypal-Debug-Id: 5ff2ab4feb8b9


(0x133dee0,0xc0001000e0)Request: POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans. Data: 
Response: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 329
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 01 Mar 2021 14:51:21 GMT
Paypal-Debug-Id: 85f6b9f24b80f

{"name":"RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND","message":"The specified resource does not exist.","debug_id":"85f6b9f24b80f","details":[{"issue":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","description":"Invalid product id"}],"links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v1/billing/subscriptions#RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND","rel":"information_link","method":"GET"}]}
```

The code I am using is:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "os"

    "github.com/plutov/paypal/v4"
)

func main() {
    c, err := paypal.NewClient(
        "",
        "",
        paypal.APIBaseSandBox)

    if err != nil {
        print(err)
    }

    c.SetLog(os.Stdout) // Set log to terminal stdout
    //print(c)

    accessToken, err := c.GetAccessToken(context.Background())
    print(accessToken)
    print("\n=======================================\n")

    listParams := paypal.ListParams{
        Page:          "1",
        PageSize:      "5",
        TotalRequired: "no",
    }

    billingPlan := paypal.BillingPlanListParams{
        ListParams: listParams,
        Status:     "ACTIVE",
    }
    _, er := c.ListBillingPlans(context.Background(), billingPlan)
    if er != nil {
        print(er)
    }
    price := paypal.Money{
        Currency: "USD",
        Value:    "10",
    }
    scheme := paypal.PricingScheme{
        FixedPrice: price,
    }
    frequency := paypal.Frequency{
        IntervalUnit:  paypal.IntervalUnitMonth,
        IntervalCount: 1,
    }
    
    newPlan := paypal.SubscriptionPlan{
        ID:          "PayPal12949",
        ProductId:   "AX12339",
        Name:        "BEGINNERS_PLAN",
        Status:      paypal.SubscriptionPlanStatusActive,
        Description: "This plan is for beginners",
        BillingCycles: []paypal.BillingCycle{
            {
                PricingScheme: scheme,
                Frequency:     frequency,
                TenureType:    paypal.TenureTypeRegular,
                Sequence:      1,
                TotalCycles:   3,
            },
        },
        PaymentPreferences: &paypal.PaymentPreferences{
            AutoBillOutstanding: false,
            SetupFee: &paypal.Money{
                Currency: "USD",
                Value:    "5",
            },
        },
    }
    c.CreateSubscriptionPlan(context.Background(), newPlan)
    
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the resource isn't found. Maybe a question for PayPal technical support?

Comment: Note that `c.ListBillingPlans` returns an error that may potentially hint to a problem with your setup, however because you are using the builtin `print` function all you see in the console is `(0x133dee0,0xc0001000e0)`. The idiomatic way to print stuff is to use the `fmt` package which knows how to properly print errors. `CreateSubscriptionPlan` also returns an error that you chose to ignore altogether, please don't do that. And finally, the error message says that `AX12339` is an invalid product id, if you believe it is valid then you should follow Flimzy's suggestion.

Comment: @mkopriva your comment definitely makes sense. Yes there is no such product available.

Answer (score 2):

That SDK is not compatible with the current version of [PayPal Subscriptions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/).

There is no supported SDK for PayPal Subscriptions; use [direct API calls](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#get-credentials).

(You could also try adapting SDK functions to implement the current subscriptions API, if you really want)

Comment: The SDK methods are translating to the API, it mentioned `[{"issue":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","description":"Invalid product id"}],` as mentioned by the other guy. And it is true I had not created any product. And on Dev interface I find no way to add subscription plans manually.

Comment: That SDK's documentation doesn't mention the current Subscriptions API calls, only the older ones, so perhaps its code has been updated but not the docs.